# How to disable network adapter in Ubuntu 19.10 (post ifupdown era)

Tags: networking, 19.10, netplan

So with Ubuntu 19.10 ifupdown got removed from the default packages.

This i found out in horror, after i was connected to my 2 networks at once, after a reboot (after upgrading to 19.10). For clarification, i have one network which is only internal and one which is external. I do not want any machine to be connected to both at once. So i pass my network card (attached to the external network) to my VM and my Host system is attached to the internal network.
This was configured via ifupdown in /etc/interfaces:

```
auto enp2s
iface enp2s inet manual
```

So the Ubuntu network GUI neither show the ethernet connection, nor connected to it.

How can i archive this functionality with netplan?

Comment: I may be wrong, but is this what you're looking for?
`ip link set enp3s0 up`
`ip link set enp3s0 down`

Source: https://netplan.io/faq#bring-interfaces-up-or-down

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/netplan on this system?  Is this a new install of Ubuntu 19.10 or an upgrade?

Comment: `ip link set enp3s0 down` kind of works, it prohibits the connection to the network on the host, which is good. But than i can't pass it to the VM.
@slangasek it was an upgrade, no new installation. There is a _01-network-manager-all.yaml_ in /etc/netplan. Which contains: `network: version: 2 renderer: NetworkManager`